# ORACLE Query Where condition based on system time

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle query below:

```
select ltrim(ROUND((1-n/c)*100) || '%') as TOTAL
from (select count(*) c 
      from WA_SEW_TBL_EMP_INFO 
      WHERE SHIFT = 'Morning')
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) n 
        FROM (SELECT S.BADGEID_FK 
              FROM WA_SEW_TBL_EMP_INFO S
              , WA_GA_TBL_EMPLOYEES E 
              WHERE S.BADGEID_FK = E.BADGEID 
              AND S.STATUS = 'Attend' 
              AND S.SHIFT = 'Morning' 
              AND S.BADGEID_FK NOT IN ( SELECT EMPID 
                                        FROM WA_SEW_TBL_RESULTS 
                                         WHERE SYSTEM_DATE between to_date ('2017-08-31 07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') 
                                                           and to_date ('2017-08-31 19:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                                         )
            )
    )
```

Shift have 2 type:

```
Night
Morning
```

Now I want oracle query detected if system time from `08:00` until `19:29` then set shift to be Morning, else Night.

means I want `WHERE SHIFT = 'system time condition  from`08:00`until`19:29`then set shift to be Morning, else Night'`

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This query uses the `'sssss'` date mask which is the number of seconds past midnight. Then you can tell whether the time element is within your desired range.

```
SELECT EMPID, 
       case when to_number(to_char(system_date, 'sssss')) 
            between 28800 -- 08:00:00
            and 70140 -- 19:29:00
            then 'Morning'
       else 'Night' as SHIFT
FROM WA_SEW_TBL_RESULTS 
where trunc(system_date) = date '2017-08-31'
```

Inject this sub-query into your main query as you need.

Incidentally I have closed the date range with a bound of seconds for 19:29:00 as you specified. Maybe that should be 70199, to take the day shift up to 19:29:59 - it depends how precisely you track time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work like this:

```
WITH TEST_DATETIME AS(
      SELECT TO_DATE('2017/08/31 10:15:24','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') DT FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('2017/08/31 19:40:24','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE WHEN to_char(DT, 'hh24:mi:ss') > '08:00:00' AND to_char(DT, 'hh24:mi:ss') < '19:29:00'  THEN 'Morning' ELSE 'Night' END AS NOON
FROM TEST_DATETIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to write function returning day/night shift and include it in your query

```
create or replace function find_shift(dat in date) return varchar2
is 
dat2 date;

treshhold1 date; 
treshhold2 date; 
ret varchar2(10);
begin 
dat2:=to_date(to_char(dat, 'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI');
treshhold1 := to_date('08:00','HH24:MI'); 
treshhold2 := to_date('19:29','HH24:MI'); 
if dat2>=treshhold1 and dat2<= treshhold2 then 
ret := 'Morning'; 
else 
ret := 'Night'; 
end if; 
return ret 
end;
```